# Ruby Array Errors. Input won't enter array issue

Tags: arrays, ruby

Whenever I run this code, the name that I want is not input correctly  into the array. The output is equal to this #=> RandomUserName
                                       #=> ["test", ""]
Its pretty annoying and it would be great if someone figured out how to input that random user name into the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'

testarray = ["test"  ].compact

password = "456789solid"
url = "http://namegeneratorbay.com/username-generator"
 userdata = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

 username1 = puts userdata.at_css('h2').text.strip

final1 = username1.to_s


testarray.push("#{final1}")



 print testarray

    sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `puts userdata.at_css('h2').text.strip` is `nil`, therefore `username1` is `nil`.

Try this instead:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

testarray = ["test"]

url = "http://namegeneratorbay.com/username-generator"
document = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
username = document.at_css('h2').text.strip

testarray.push(username)

puts testarray
#=> ["test", "Rhirawyr"]
```